# WCF - set MaxReceivedMessageSize for single OperationContract

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

Is it possible to set the MaxReceivedMessageSize of a WCF binding for a single OperationContract instead of globally for all ServiceContracts that are bound to the binding? I have about two dozen operations in my ServiceContract of which only one is likely to receive (streamed) messages larger than the default, and I want to leave the default message size for all other operations as a simple DoS protection mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution may be you can add your binding through coding for a particular operation/method.